# How do I count multiple columns with a vertical value?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm new to programing. I have table

```
check_1,check_2,check_3 ..etc
------------------------------
 1       1       1
 0       0       1
 1       0       1
```

And I want this output :

```
column_name, count_true
-----------------------
  check_1       2
  check_2       1
  check_3       3
```

I've tried it with mysql using the union function, but when I try to apply it in laravel I have trouble with union. Is there a unionless query that can produce such output?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How many columns do you actually have?  Note that a better table design would be to just have two columns, one for the check number and the other for 0/1.

Comment: 24 columns, :) thank you for the advice but all the columns to save the results of checking from the checkbox

Comment: Yes. Fix your schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way. One query in db

```
$records = DB::table('your_table')->get();
$check1Count = $records->where('check_1', 1)->count();
$check2Count = $records->where('check_2', 1)->count();
$check3Count = $records->where('check_3', 1)->count();
......
```

Or

```
$records = DB::table('your_table')->get();
$columns = ['check_1', 'check_2', 'check_3', ...];
$data = [];
foreach($columns as $column) {
    $data[] = [
        'column_name' => $column,
        'count_true' => $records->where($column, 1)->count();
    ];
}
```

Also you can do this way but it is many query

```
$check1Count = DB::table('your_table')
    ->selectRaw('COUNT(check_1) as count')
    ->where('check_1', 1)
    ->first()
    ->count;

$check2Count = DB::table('your_table')
    ->selectRaw('COUNT(check_2) as count')
    ->where('check_2', 1)
    ->first()
    ->count;
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

A normalised approach might look like this:

```
response_id  checkbox
          1         1
          1         2
          1         3
          2         3
          3         1
          3         3
```

Comment: This is not a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need union, just query all the data and process it on Laravel. Let say you query all the data using eloquent to $data variable, then you should do it like this:

```
//preparing a variable to hold all 24 database field value
$total = [];
foreach ($data as $d) {
    //do this for all 24 database field
    if ($d->check_1) {
        $total[1]++;
    }
    if ($d->check_2) {
        $total[2]++;
    }
    ...
}
```

By using that way you can't check the resutl on $total[index] variable. And yes, there is a better way to store your data instead of saving all the field for each user. You can just store all checked value in database that look like this :

```
user_id checkbox_id
      1           3
      1           5
      1           9
      1          24
      2          23
      3           2
      3           3
```

It more efficient since you don't need to save the unchecked checkbox value, if they more likely not to checked most of the checkbox.